# What is the equivalent value of document.getElementById().setCustomValidity() in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello my problem is to create an equivalent value of document.getElementById().setCustomValidity() in Reactjs  for my Registration form to validate firstname input field

here's my code

```
function CreateAcc() {

   const[name,setName] = useState({firstname:''})

   const onChangehHandle = e => setName({firstname: e.target.value})

   const onblr = () =>{
      if(name.firstname==''){
          //here i just want to change the alert to document.getElementById().setCustomValidity() to 
            validate the firstname input field
          
         alert('Please fill out this input field')
      }
  } 
   return (
      <div>
        
        <form id='createAccForm'>
        <h2>Create Account</h2>
        <div className='text-box'>
            <label><FaUserCircle size='20px'/></label>
            <input className='createAccInputInline' id = 'firstname' type='name' name = 'firstname' placeholder='First Name' onBlur={onblr} value ={name.firstname} onChange={onChangehHandle}/>
            <input className='createAccInputInline' type='name' name = 'lastname' placeholder='Last Name' />
        </div>

        <div className='text-box'>
            <label htmlFor = 'email'><MdEmail size='20px'/></label>
            <input id = 'email' type='email' placeholder='Email Address'/>
        </div>

        <div className='text-box'>
            <label><BsFillLockFill size='20px'/></label>
            <input className='createAccInputInline' type='password' placeholder='Password'/>
            <input className='createAccInputInline' type='password' placeholder='Confirm Password'/>
        </div>

        <button id = 'createAccButton'>Sign Up</button>

        </form>
    </div>
)
}

export default CreateAcc
```

Comment: `setCustomValidity` *sets the custom validity message for the selection element to the specified message* - but your question seems to want to read that value? or am I misundertanding?

Comment: You need to use refs and then set the custom validy on mount.. and then in the blur option you can trigger the checkvalidity with reds... the second option would be a controlled components...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate onblr function. We can set custom validation message using `setCustomValidity()` method inside `onChangeHandle`.

```
   const onChangehHandle = name = e => {
     setName({[name]: e.target.value});
     if(name=='firstname' && e.target.value == '') {
       event.target.setCustomValidity("Please fill out this input field");    
     } else {
       event.target.setCustomValidity('');
     }
```